# JSF2 UTF-8 Encoding issue with saving data into database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jsf

I have added below code in my web.xml file

```
  <filter>
      <filter-name>forceUTF8CharSet</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>forceUTF8CharSet</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

In database i have made these changes

```
CREATE TABLE `group_distribution` (
  `gd_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gd_tweet` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `gd_ht` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_team_lead` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_send_to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_added_dt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `gt_update_dt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_active_flag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gd_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and when i am maually inserting data into Db through MySQL Client its working fine but when i am inserting same data with JSF page database showing data like this

```
??????? ?? ?????? ?? ???????? ?????? ?? ?????? ???? ????? ??? ????? ???????? ??? ?? ?????? ?? ??? ???? ??? Test data
```

Also in template file i added this line

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

JSF page able to show data in Hindi font but same data when going to Db showing ???????

Comment: Did you create the database schema using the right [charset and collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html)?

Comment: Database created 1 year back but now i am checking for Hindi Support by DB and manually i am able to insert Hindi Fonts in DB but from application not working i already done `SET NAMES 'utf8';`

Comment: Which application server are you using ?

Comment: I am using tomcat7.0.29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Primefaces Group member in Facebook Got the solution in my **application-context.xml** file i changed the jdbc url

```
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:3306/ccc?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8" />
```

Which was look like below previously

```
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:3306/ccc " />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this to web.xml

```
  <jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.*</url-pattern>
      <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
  </jsp-config>
```

in tomcat/config/server.xml file add the  URIEncoding="UTF-8" to the connector as the following:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: Did you add the UTF8 encoding to the server.xml in the tomcat config folder?

Comment: No But it is working now i added in web.xml and connection URL and also in DB table